# Hide Navigationbar not working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am using following code for hiding the `NavigationBar` of the `View`  :

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:YES];
```

(I am using iOS 6) am I doing something wrong?

Comment: where u adding above code?

Comment: try it in viewWillAppear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same code in `viewWillAppear. It shall work.